# wp_get_attachment_url images in wrong order

Tags: images, order, xml

I have this bit of code in my xml feed and it's picking up the images in a different order than it is in the WordPress post.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E89eg.png

Here in the admin area I can drag the images around, and the page will display the top left image first and the bottom right image last. I would like my xml feed to give the images the same order.
Thanks!

```
$attimages = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
                          $counter = 1;
                          foreach ($attimages as $image) {
                            if ($counter <= 50) {
                              echo '<image id="'.$counter.'"><url>'.wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID).'</url></image>' . "\r\n";
                            }
                            $counter++;
                          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Gallerys aren't implemented the way you're pulling in images, the images in a gallery might not be attached to the post at all.

`get_attached_media` will give you the images attached to the post by the order of their ID.

This means:

- Images you added to the post, then deleted will be in this array
- Images in galleries attached to other posts won't be in this array

If we think it through logically, if your post had 2 galleries, each with the same photos but ordered differently, how would that work? Which order is correct? Neither. This function has nothing to do with Galleries

### So What Are Galleries Then?

Shortcodes/Blocks.

E.g. shortcode:

```html
[gallery ids="1,2,5,4"]
```

Or block:

```html
<!-- wp:gallery {"ids":[36,30,22,15,14]} -->
<figure class="wp-block-gallery columns-3 is-cropped"><ul class="blocks-gallery-grid"><li class="blocks-gallery-item"><figure><img src="http://one.wordpress.test/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/be.png" alt="" data-id="36" data-full-url="http://one.wordpress.test/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/be.png" data-link="http://one.wordpress.test/be/" class="wp-image-36"/></figure></li>...etc...</ul></figure>
<!-- /wp:gallery -->
```

The order of the IDs in the attributes is what determines the order. Using `get_attached_media` to try to recreate a gallery in content is a dead end that will not work. You need to look at the shortcode/block instead

Comment: Hey thanks for the informative post. I've tried digging through the website as it is not one that I created, but could not find any shortcode. I have found that the gallery is created with Jet Engine plugin; https://crocoblock.com/knowledge-base/articles/jetengine-dynamic-field-widget-grid-gallery-and-slider-gallery-options-overview/

Comment: Ah then it will not be possible to answer your question without internal knowledge of that plugin. The use of that plugin is super critical information that was not shared in your OP, and confirms that you were never using a gallery at all, you were using a custom solution purchased from crocoblock. You need to contact their support or refer to their docs, 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here

Comment: I see. Well you've answered a lot of my questions. Will go ahead and do as you suggest. Thank you so much.